# MRTG Monitoring of Disk

Tags: snmp

I am trying to monitor Disk usage over SNMP using MRTG on CentOS5.2. I'm open to any suggestions as to the best way to achieve this (I would also like to do other metrics like CPU). Please don't assume I know anything about MRTG.

I am using the following config:

```
LoadMIBs: /usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-SNMP-MIB.txt,/usr/share/snmp/mibs/TCP-MIB.txt
workdir: /var/www/html/mrtg/temp/
#
# Disk Usage Monitoring
#

Target[servername.]: dskPercent.0&dskPercent.0:OpenNm3@192.168.1.2
Title[servername.]: / on servername
routers.cgi*Desc[servername.]: / on servername
routers.cgi*ShortDesc[servername.]: /
MaxBytes[servername.]: 100
AbsMax[servername.]: 100
Options[servername.]: growright,nopercent,gauge
YLegend[servername.]: used disk space
ShortLegend[servername.]: % used
Legend1[servername.]: usage
Legend2[servername.]: usage
Legend3[servername.]: peak usage
Legend4[servername.]: peak usage
LegendI[servername.]: usage
LegendO[servername.]: usage
routers.cgi*Icon[servername.]: disk-sm.gif
routers.cgi*Options[servername.]: noo,nomax,noabsmax
Unscaled[servername.]: dwmy
```

I receive the errors:

```
Unknown SNMP var dskPercent.0
 at /usr/bin/mrtg line 2035
Unknown SNMP var dskPercent.0
 at /usr/bin/mrtg line 2035
```

From forum surfing etc the suggestion is to use the fully qualified OIDs, I'd like to avoid this (for readability). So essentially I'm wondering where can I find a mib file compatible with mrtg for it's reference or a working config file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not wedded to MRTG, I'd suggest Cacti as a superior SNMP-based monitoring tool.  Cacti understands the MIBs ahead of time and you should be able to just select the partitions you want to monitor.

Cacti can be installed via Yum from the RPMforge repository.

Comment: likely this is the direction I'll head; I'm not fixated on MRTG; mostly it just bugs me I've never been able to get it working.

Comment: As I doubt anyone will step forward with the answer and this was the solution that eventually implemented I'll flag it as the answer... 

Honestly it was easier than direct config of MRTG and produced more what I was eventually looking for anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of dskPercent, try using `hrStorageUsed.x`

Give the command `snmpwalk -v1 -c <communityname> localhost hrStorage`, and you will get list of values you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to use the `dskPercent` OID nickname in MRTG, you need to load the `UCD-SNMP-MIB`, which you are doing.  So the error you see has nothing to do with the MIB not being loaded into MRTG.  Trying to put the full OID will not help.

Rather it is your snmp agent on the machine you're trying to monitor which doesn't have any entry in the `dskTable`.  This table is only populated if you have one or multiple `disk` configuration lines in your `snmpd.conf` configuration file (provided you use [net-snmp](http://www.net-snmp.org/)).  For example, you can have 2 lines like:

```
disk    /
disk    /var
```

To make sure the snmp tree does contain the `dskPercent` table after such a configuration, check with a CLI snmp tool, for example:

```
snmpwalk -v2c -C yourcommunity localhost dskTable
```

(or, if your snmpwalk is not configured to used OID nicknames)

```
snmpwalk -v2c -C yourcommunity localhost .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.9.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using MRTG with Routers2, there is a generic cfgmaker host template available at http://www.steveshipway.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=1616 which will automatically generate MRTG configurations for many things, including the storage OIDs.  These take advantage of the Routers2 additional features to give you combination graphs.  It should work with any SNMP-capable host.

You can use it with standard MRTG cfgmaker like this:

```
cfgmake --host-template=generic.htp community@device > device.cfg
```